# Intermittent XmlSerializer (partially) null file

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, xml-serialization, streamwriter

I'm using an XmlSerializer with a StreamWriter as follows:

```
...
string xmlFile = GetXMLLocation(objToSaveType);
XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(objToSaveType);
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(xmlFile))
    Serializer.Serialize(sw, objToSave);
...
```

This works the vast majority of the time, but rarely the generated file is full of null characters, and once in a while the offending file only ends in null characters, eg.

```
...
        <Extension>0</Extension>
      </OrderProductLine>
      <OrderProductLine>
        <ProductDescription />
        <Commission>0.3</Commission>
        <UnitType />
        <UnitPrice>0</UnitPrice>
        <UnitQuantity>0</UnitQuantity>
        <PackageType />
        <Extension>0</Extension>
   [null x ~1 million]
```

I've never been able to reproduce it myself. It doesn't generate any errors while serializing and seems to only occur while the program is shutting down.

Related questions:

- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635519/xmlserializer-saves-null-file) - obvious fix, writer isn't flushing; I'm using `using` which calls Dispose() which is the same as Close()
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380424/will-xmlserializer-ever-create-empty-documents) - best answer supposes an error was missed; mine generates no error; empty file and one filled with nulls are not the same. Nonetheless, one of the answers suggests this is a caching issue.

I have modified my code as follows in case the caching issue idea is right:

```
string xmlFile = GetXMLLocation(objToSaveType);
XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(objToSaveType);
using (Stream file = new FileStream(xmlFile, FileMode.Create,
                         FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None,
                         0x1000, FileOptions.WriteThrough))
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file))
        Serializer.Serialize(sw, objToSave);
```

I have some ideas for workarounds (mainly, deserialize immediately after saving, rollback or try again if there's a problem), but it'd be great to fix the darn thing. Since it's so intermittent I don't yet know if the above fixed it or not. This post is either to inform others in a similar situation of a possible fix or to get ideas for other possible causes. Thanks for reading. (P.S. First SO post, sorry if I've broken any protocols!)

Update: a little over a week later, the bug has yet to reappear. My fingers are crossed, though I'll really need around a month to know with reasonable certainty if this fixed things.

Update: two and a half weeks later, still good.

Hopefully final update: over a month later, still good. Caching seems to have been the problem after all, yay!

Comment: We have seen this error, too; it mainly happened "in the field" (we notice it, when customers complain that they have lost data). Which version of .Net do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I talked to a colleague what we did to fix this issue in our application.

We saved some xml data when the application shut down, and it looks like that sometimes the thread who writes the file to disk is killed by the application shutdown process.

We moved the save command away from the application shutdown to the time when the data was changed. That solved the problem for us.

Comment: I actually tried that without effect, which surprised me. Specifically, I moved the shutdown save call from the Application_Exit event to the Window_Closing event of my main launch screen--the setup of the app forces you to close through this one place. This is sub-optimal but happens to work in my case. Incidentally, it did fix another issue: creating a new window in App_Exit rarely threw an error.